# "Unknown file extension" error with Nuxtjs/google-fonts package

Tags: nuxt.js, file-extension

Following the [docs](https://google-fonts.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup), I installed the package through `npm install -D @nuxtjs/google-fonts` (since I'm using `Nuxt v2.14.7`) then added '@nuxtjs/google-fonts' to my `buildModules` array in `nuxt.config.js`.

Just by doing that, I immediately get this error:

> FATAL  Unknown file extension:
> D:\projects...\node_modules\pathe\dist\index.cjs
>
> Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension:
> node_modules\pathe\dist\index.cjs at
> /D:/projects/.../node_modules/@nuxtjs/google-fonts/dist/module.mjs:1
> at Generator.next ()

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `node_modules` folder,
2. Delete `package.lock.json`,
3. Clean up the NPM cache by running `npm cache clean --force`,
4. Finally , you can try to `npm install`

if this not work, try to remove `@nuxtjs/google-fonts` with `npm remove @nuxtjs/google-fonts` and reinstall it `npm install -D @nuxtjs/google-fonts`

I hope this work

Comment: Thanks, but after doing all of this I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check your configurations and the way you import with modules based on whether you use CommonJS module or ES module.

```
// For CommonJS module:
const pathe = require('pathe');

// For ES module:
import * as pathe from 'pathe';
```

And if you are using ES module, in package.json make sure to add this code section:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using this package `pathe` anywhere in my codebase. I just get an error mentioning it when enabling Nuxtjs/google-fonts

Comment: It seems that google-fonts are importing '.cjs' files but it is not recognized by your node.js environment.
If you are using CommonJs module, make sure there is no "type": "module" in your package.json, as this would instruct Node.js to treat '.js' files as ES modules by default, which might conflict with CommonJS '.cjs' files.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few potential solutions for this problem:

1. Downgrade your Node.js version: Downgrading your Node.js version to 19.8.1 or earlier may solve this issue. You can use Node Version Manager (nvm) to easily switch between Node.js versions.(this procedure usually eliminates the problem.)
2. Clear the npm cache: Sometimes the npm cache can cause issues. Clear the cache by running npm cache clean --force
3. Delete node_modules and package-lock.json: You can try deleting the node_modules folder and package-lock.json, then run npm install again.
4. Use Yarn instead of npm: Yarn is an alternative package manager that can sometimes handle dependencies better than npm.

Here's an example of downgrading your Node.js version using nvm:

`nvm install 19.8.1`
`nvm use 19.8.1`

How to clean the npm cache:
`npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Thanks but I tried many versions of Node already (1) and by now I did (2) and (3) multiple times..